# Encryption in xamarin cross platform PCL

Tags: xamarin

I want to implement encryption methods (for ios and android) in my xamarin cross platform PCL component without adding any encryption portable class libraries(like bouncy castle).How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an abstraction. This could be achieved through Inversion of Control, where you make an Interface describing the capabilities of your encryption class.

Then you implement that Interface for each platform you want to support.

At runtime you would then swap in the actual implementation for that platform, while your PCL would only know the Interface for it.

Typically this is either achieved using an IoC container. However, you could also use the Bait and Switch pattern.

Instead of relying on your own Crypto code, I would really consider looking into PCLCrypto, Bouncy Castle or some other existing library, which you can use in your Xamarin/PCL code.

Comment: I have two concerns to clarify,                                                                                   1.If I am using the PCLCrypto,Bouncy Castle or any other portable class libraries for encryption,then whoever referencing my PCL component has to reference the same above libraries in their project.Is it going to add any extra memory in their apk and in my component size?(also PCL Crypto is throwing errors in android build)  2. I am using MVVM light as IOC .Do you have any other suggestions?Also can you provide some examples to my scenario?